# Rename parameters / field in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm using Rails 4.2.5 and the latest version of ActiveAdmin in a Rails test project. I would like to rename a parameter in ActiveAdmin just like I can do with [the name of the class](http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#rename-the-resource), but I haven't found an easy way to do that.

Let's suppose the following model:

```
Employee
    name:string
    role:string
```

I want that ActiveAdmin shows the "role" parameter as "Cargo" ("*role*" in brazilian portuguese) throughout all administrative panel.

**I'm currently using the following workaround:**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Employee, as: "empregado" do

    permit_params :name, :role

    # Rename the desired parameter in /admin/empregados
    index do
        column "Nome", :name
        column "Cargo", :role
        actions
    end

    # Rename the desired parameter in /admin/empregados/new
    form do |f|
         inputs do
            input :name, label: "Nome"
            input :role, label: "Cargo"
        end
        actions
    end

    # Rename the desired parameter in /admin/empregados/[:id]
    show do
        attributes_table do
            row :id
            row("Nome"){ empregado.name }
            row("Cargo"){ empregado.role }
            row("Criado em"){ empregado.created_at }
            row("Atualizado em"){ empregado.updated_at }
        end
    end
end
```

This works, but it's quite manual and I don't think this is the "Railsistic way" to do things. Also, there's some places where the model wasn't renamed, like the "filters" for the search:
[image]

I would like to find an easy way to rename this column / parameter throughout all administrative panel without need to replicate code. There's a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveAdmin uses ActiveRecord's translations when displaying anything related to a model, so in your case you could just add something like this to your es.yml file:

```
es:
  activerecord:
    models:
      employee:
        one: Empregado
    attributes:
      employee:
        name: Nome
        role: Cargo
        created_at: Criado em
        updated_at: Atualizado em
```